# Multiple exist points for a nodejs controller with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

The following snippet of code is a nodeJS controller method calling a service that returns a deferred promise. Im trying to understand the best way to handle multiple exist points.

For example, if the service returns an empty object I want the promise chain to exist and return the response 'Nothing found here' to the user. If it does find something, it moves from step 1 onto the next item in the promise chain i.e. step 2.

From my testing, it seems to be returning the json response and then dropping in to the next logic step i.e. step 2. This logic cant be handled in the service right now i.e. if no item is found to return an error.

```
module.exports.show = function (req, res) {

    service.getItem(itemId)
        .then(function (item) { 
            if (!item) {
                return res.json('Nothing found here');
            }
           // Step 1             
           // do some work on the item    
            return item;
        })
        .then(function (foundItem) {
           // Step 2             
           // do some more work on the item
           return res.json('Item has changed ' + foundItem);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
           return res.json(err);
        });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. The Error is caught by the catch handler. I also changed the if-clause (I assumed that's what you actually meant):

```
module.exports.show = function (req, res) {

    service.getItem(itemId)
    .then(function (item) { 
        if (!item) {
            throw new Error('Nothing found here');
        }
       // Step 1             
       // do some work on the item    
        return item;
    })
    .then(function (foundItem) {
       // Step 2             
       // do some more work on the item
       return res.json('Item has changed ' + foundItem);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
       return res.json(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: Exactly right. Promises only jump to catch blocks when an `Error` object is thrown.

Comment: Incorrect, a promise chain will jump to the next catch block if *anything* is thrown. It is generally a good idea to throw an Error.

Comment: There are more cases. A promise can fall to catch handler if you return, for example, a rejected promise, like in `return Promise.reject(new Error("Rejected error"));`

Comment: Yes indeed, that is also true.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `then` always returns a promise. If you don't return a promise yourself, a resolved promise is automatically created with the return value.

So, `return res.json('Nothing found here')` is the same as `return Promise.resolve(res.json('Nothing found here'));`, which means that next `then` will, obvisouly, be called.

If you don't want to execute the next then, you just have to reject the promise :

```
throw new Error('Nothing found here'));
// ...
.catch(function (err) {
   return res.json(err.message);
});
```

By the way you probably meant `if (!item)`, not `if (item)` :

```
if (!item) {
    throw new Error('Nothing found here');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Steps 1 and 2 are synchronous, then :

```
module.exports.show = function (req, res) {
    service.getItem(itemId).then(function (item) { 
        if (!item) {
            throw new Error('Nothing found here'); // this will be caught below
        }
        item = doWork_2(doWork_1(item)); // Steps 1 and 2: 
        return res.json('Item has changed ' + item);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return res.json(err.message);
    });
};
```

where `doWork_1()` and `doWork_2()` both return the processed `item`.

If Steps 1 and 2 are asynchronous, then :

```
module.exports.show = function (req, res) {
    service.getItem(itemId).then(function (item) { 
        if (!item) {
            throw new Error('Nothing found here'); // this will be caught below
        } else {
            return doWork_1(item).then(doWork_2); // Step 1, then Step 2
        }
    })
    .then(function (item) {
        return res.json('Item has changed ' + item);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return res.json(err.message);
    });
};
```

where `doWork_1()` and `doWork_2()` return a promise resolved with the processed `item`.

If it is uncertain whether `doWork_1()` and `.doWork_2()` are synchronous or asynchronuus, then use the following pattern, which will handle both eventualities :

```
module.exports.show = function (req, res) {
    service.getItem(itemId).then(function (item) { 
        if (!item) {
            throw new Error('Nothing found here'); // this will be caught below
        } else {
            return item;
        }
    })
    .then(doWork_1) // Step 1
    .then(doWork_2) // Step 2
    .then(function (item) {
        return res.json('Item has changed ' + item);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return res.json(err.message);
    });
};
```